# How to send error from API

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm writing a WEB API.

However, even though there's is an error, in the swift code, inside the Alamofire request, "isSuccess" is always equals to true.

What should I send in the JSON to let Alamofire detect that there's an error? ( is.Failure = true).

The server is sending me error code 404, however it looks like it always succeed:

```
      Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users", parameters: ["username" : usernameString, "limit":3] , headers: ["tb-token" : userToken!])
            .responseJSON { _, _, result in


                print(result.value)

                switch result {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
                    self.tableView.hidden = false

                    self.resultsDict = result.value as! NSArray

                    let results = result.value
                    let resultsNumber = results!.count

                    self.numberOfResults.text = "Results(\(resultsNumber))"
                    self.numberOfResults.hidden = false

                    self.resultsN = resultsNumber
                    self.loadedMode = true


                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.tableView.hidden = false
                case .Failure(let data, let error):
                    print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
                }

        }
```

[EDIT]
I've uploaded to Alamofire 3.0, but I still got the same problem.
Here's the new code:

```
         Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users", parameters: ["username" : usernameString, "limit":3] , headers: ["tb-token" : userToken!])
            .responseJSON { response in


                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization


                let results = response.result

                if let JSON = response.result.value {

                    if response.result.isSuccess == true {
                        print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
                        self.tableView.hidden = false

                        self.resultsDict = results.value as! NSArray

                        let resultsNumber = results.value!.count

                        self.numberOfResults.text = "Results(\(resultsNumber))"
                        self.numberOfResults.hidden = false

                        self.resultsN = resultsNumber
                        self.loadedMode = true


                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.tableView.hidden = false
                    }
                }
                    else {print("error")}

        }
```

Here's response.response:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fa1bb216a50> { URL: http://teambuilding-adall.rhcloud.com/api/users?limit=3&username=adallo } { status code: 404, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Length" = 60;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sat, 10 Oct 2015 23:32:13 GMT";
Etag = "W/\"3c-dR4AnAjVi0TRWls1iKAm7w\"";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=60";
"X-Powered-By" = Express;
} })
```

[FINAL EDIT] I solved this by adding these two lines of code:

```
.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
.validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
```

Comment: add your complete code

Comment: Added the code! @Johnny

Comment: Could you add the output of `print(response.response)` please?

Comment: Added to the question! @EricD.

Comment: But I'm checking isSuccess, which should only depend on the response code, regardless of the content... @EricD.

Answer (score 0):

From browsing over the Alamofire GitHub page as well as general practice, you should send a non 200 status code to indicate failure. The specific status code should correspond to the type or reason for the error.

Usually you will send a 4xx status code (e.x. 400, 403, 404, 409). Read up on which status codes to send when here: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: It's not working like that.. I've added the code anyway.